# Twilio statuscallback

Tags: twilio

My application receives an incoming call, modifies it to register a statuscallback URL and then queues it. If the caller hangs up call before it is picked off the queue, then the statuscallback URL is not called by Twilio. statuscallback URL, however, is called if the call is picked up and then either party then hangs up.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

Instead of modifying the call's statuscallback, if you want to know that the call hung up before being picked from the queue, you can set the [`action`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue#attributes-action) parameter on the `<Enqueue>` verb.  This URL will get called whenever the call leaves the queue, and will pass you a parameter called [`QueueResult`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue#attributes-action-parameters-QueueResult) that tells you why they left the queue, including they hung up.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know that call is hang up before picked from queue
you can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="wait-music.xml" action="statuscallback.php">support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="wait-music.xml" action="statuscallback.php" >support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```